# k9copy concerns

Tags: malware

I downloaded k9copy from tomtomtom and test installed it. After installing the program wouldn't run from unity but did run from terminal. It opened a window and I did a test rip on a movie in my collection. It ran and completed the rip but then i noticed it had generated a bunch of lines in terminal.

Example:

```
kbuildsycoca4 running...
kbuildsycoca4(26860)/kdecore (services) KServicePrivate::parseActions: The desktop file "/usr/share/applications/GooglePlusplusgooglecom.desktop" references the action "S0" but doesn't define it
```

My concern is that it did that for email accounts, social media accounts, and it picked up a personal file from my documents folder.

Why would this k9copy be running through email, social media and personal files. Is this some kind of malware looking for a users information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

k9copy uses kbuildsycoca4, which in turn uses kdecore. kdecore provides actions to other programs like kbuildsycoca4. kdecore has spotted is a small configuration error in the launcher file of GooglePlusplusgooglecom.desktop. A launcher file is used to display an icon for a program and start it. I guess you have some kind of Google+ application installed with an incorrect launch desktop file.

Nothing to worry about, it won't cause problems. kdecore was just verifying your launcher files. Just a warning, not a fatal error.

Comment: The Google+ part is what got my attention.  That and Yahoo Facebook,  LinkdIn, Youtube and Twitter. It had similar lines for each of these. I have purposely not installed any apps from any of these. I do have a Gmail account but i only access it through Firefox. Also, why did it pick up an odt file from my Documents folder, I had other odt files in there but that was the only file with sensitive financial information. It may be nothing but is sure seemed odd.

Comment: The reason for this is probably that kdecore also provides social media functions and verifies these working correctly when starting kdecore. About the odt file, not sure. I need to see the output for that one :)